# Which version of Hadoop is compatible with Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: hadoop

Which version of Hadoop is compatible with Ubuntu 17.10 ?

Comment: It should be the latest stable release. Googling "hadoop ubuntu 17.10" has a tutorial on the first link.

Answer (score 1):

The only requirement for Apache Hadoop is to have installed JDK. Hadoop 2.6 and earlier supports Java 6, 2.7-2.9 supports Java 7, 3.0.0 and newer supports Java 8. So, if you have Java 8 in your Ubuntu, you can use any version of Hadoop. But it's recommended to use new releases from here: http://hadoop.apache.org/releases.html (2.7.5 or newer). It can depend on what software you want to use with your Hadoop cluster.